# How to convert inline images from Email-To-Case to Attachments?

Tags: apex

I came across [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/salesforce/comments/4gi7kg/storage_issues_make_inline_images_on_emails/) question from reddit.com/r/salesforce.

> We are currently running at 98% of our 22gb data usage and we have
>   worked out that this is caused because of customers and our employees
>   sending images to each other inline in emails, not as attachments.
>   Attachments count towards our file storage, not data. We have hundreds
>   of GBs free of file space. Has anyone found a way to convert all
>   inline images to attachments?

What's interesting is that having inline images stored in the email of the case was introduced from [Summer '15 release](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Gp9dAAC), as it was a hot topic on the IdeaExchange and users requested it. Previously, inline images were attached as Attachments under the case.

So for some orgs, this may be a 'unintended consequence', in that inline images can add to more data storage consumption, if an org has a large volume of email to case workflows.

Data storage is relatively expensive in Salesforce as it can be [x25 more expensive than file storage](https://www.shellblack.com/data/storage/), and tends to be more heavily consumed in most orgs than file storage.

**Question:**

What is a smart way to convert these inline images to Attachments? How best would one resolve this issue? Has anyone faced this same issue and if so, how did you resolve it?

I was thinking that using a scheduled job to find all emails that have been created over a certain period of time which have an inline image regex could be flagged, but then the conversion to an attachment seems a bit messy, and i'm not sure if the regex for inline images would be universal.